# Android Listview Next-Prev Buttons for show items

Tags: android, listview

I m starting android development and I m learning. I m making some kind of list application.

My application **connects my server every 10 seconds and get 10 items**, and **append retrieved item onto to the listview**.

I want to **show just one item at a time**, I have **previous** and **next** button.

I want to make listview almost like this :

[image]

How can I do like this listview (*I don't want to show small pictures left or right like this pic, **I just want to move or reload new items When I click the prev or next Button***)?

Does anyone know any way or any tutorial on this subject?

**Note :** I do'nt want to refresh my activity, I know making this way but its not for my application.

Comment: you don't want left or right pic, bu want to perform click on prev/next button? Don't you think this is confusing?

Comment: Why don't you use ViewPager?

Comment: @PareshMayani Actually I want to say I dont want to full copy like this pic, I just want to move items clicking button.

Comment: @sUndeep thank you for your suggestion. I didnt know what is ViewPager, I m searching now.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a ListView for this, I'd have a look at using a `ViewPager`.

[ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

To set the width of each page, override `getPageWidth()` in your PagerAdapter

[getPageWidth()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getPageWidth%28int%29)

You can then use a `PageTransformer` to modify each page's `View` relative to its position in the ViewPager.

[PageTransformer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html)

[Examples](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Comment: Hş @jmcdonnell40 I m checkin ViewPager but its not working Api Level < 14. So, I have to find another way to do it. Because my aplication have to work Api level 9-10-11..

Comment: Use support library (android-support-v*.jar) so as to compatible with OS below 3.0

Comment: Ah yes, the ViewPager is **only** in the Support library

Comment: Actually I cant find any way for this problem. Any idea?